# Show / Hide rows of nested, dynamic table using Bootstrap Collapse

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to produce a table that shows a leaderboard, with varying degrees of detail, for a sports league. The data itself is coming from a SQL database. I have a number of teams, each team comprises a varying number of players (note: a player can belong to more than 1 team) and each player earns money by participating in a varying number of events (note: more than 1 player can participate in an event). Team names are unique.

I would like the table to initially show just the total earnings for each team, and then when the row of a team is clicked, the details of just that team's players are shown.  Then, when the row of a player is clicked, the event details for that player on that team are displayed. A 2nd click of the row would hide the data that had been revealed.

Dynamically setting the data-target and id attributes is tripping me up. With all the options that I have tried, a click has no effect.  If I hard-code these values (sample shown below), the table works in the way I would expect, but obviously not in the way I want.  In other words, it reveals all data for the requested level, across all parents - but it should be for just the selected parent. In the snippet, I'm using a simplified array in place of the call to the db.

Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/gistewart/e9qyLv20/

```js
const arr = [{
    teamName: "team1",
    teamEarnings: "$1700",
    teamPlayers: [{
        playerName: "player1",
        playerEarnings: "$1000",
        events: [{
          eventName: "event1",
          eventEarnings: "$400"
        }, {
          eventName: "event2",
          eventEarnings: "$600"
        }],
      },
      {
        playerName: "player2",
        playerEarnings: "$700",
        events: [{
          eventName: "event2",
          eventEarnings: "$500"
        }, {
          eventName: "event3",
          eventEarnings: "$200"
        }],
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    teamName: "team2",
    teamEarnings: "$2900",
    teamPlayers: [{
        playerName: "player1",
        playerEarnings: "$900",
        events: [{
          eventName: "event1",
          eventEarnings: "$800"
        }, {
          eventName: "event3",
          eventEarnings: "$100"
        }],
      },
      {
        playerName: "player3",
        playerEarnings: "$2000",
        events: [{
          eventName: "event2",
          eventEarnings: "$1250"
        }, {
          eventName: "event3",
          eventEarnings: "$750"
        }],
      }
    ],
  }
]

function displayLeaderboard(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $(".leaderboard-container").append(
      "<tr data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#demo1' class='clickabe'><td>" + arr[i].teamName + "</td><td>" + arr[i].teamEarnings + "</td></tr>"
    )
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].teamPlayers.length; j++) {
      $(".leaderboard-container").append(
        "<tr class='level2 hiddenRow collapse' id='demo1' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#demo2' class='clickable'><td>" + arr[i].teamPlayers[j].playerName + "</td><td>" + arr[i].teamPlayers[j].playerEarnings + "</td></tr>"
      )
      for (let k = 0; k < arr[i].teamPlayers[j].events.length; k++) {
        $(".leaderboard-container").append(
          "<tr class='level3 hiddenRow collapse' id='demo2' ><td>" + arr[i].teamPlayers[j].events[k].eventName + "</td><td>" + arr[i].teamPlayers[j].events[k].eventEarnings + "</td></tr>"
        )
      }
    }
  }
}

displayLeaderboard(arr);
```

```css
.level2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: blue;
}

.level3 {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table leaderboard-container">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Team</th>
          <th scope="col">Earnings</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do, You have to add specific identifier to each called collapse element from parent:

```
  function displayLeaderboard(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      $(".leaderboard-container").append(
        "<tr data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#demo"+ i +"' class='clickabe'><td>" + arr[i].teamName + "</td><td>" + arr[i].teamEarnings + "</td></tr>"
      )
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].teamPlayers.length; j++) {
        $(".leaderboard-container").append(
          "<tr class='level2 hiddenRow collapse' id='demo"+ i +"' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#demo-"+ i +"-"+ j +"' class='clickable'><td>" + arr[i].teamPlayers[j].playerName + "</td><td>" + arr[i].teamPlayers[j].playerEarnings + "</td></tr>"
        )
        for (let k = 0; k < arr[i].teamPlayers[j].events.length; k++) {
          $(".leaderboard-container").append(
            "<tr class='level3 hiddenRow collapse' id='demo-"+ i +"-"+ j +"' ><td>" + arr[i].teamPlayers[j].events[k].eventName + "</td><td>" + arr[i].teamPlayers[j].events[k].eventEarnings + "</td></tr>"
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }

  displayLeaderboard(arr);
```

Hope it helps.